# Flex 3.5 - NetStream - StackOverflow errors when calling publish() after calling close()

Tags: apache-flex, netstream, soundcloud-stratus

I'm getting stack overflow errors when I'm trying to publish() a NetStream after close()ing it. Pasted below is the error stack:

Error: Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred.
    at com.luxideus.facebook.canvas.controllers::StreamsController/onNetStatus()[...]
    at flash.net::NetStream/invokeWithArgsArray()
    at flash.net::NetStream/call()
    at flash.net::NetStream/publish()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't figure it out. Switched to AFCS, which seems to be better supported by Adobe and thus is a better platform to invest in.